# Custom Scheduled Query in Google BigQuery using timezone

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using scheduled query in Google BigQuery,
The requirement is to set it every 1st month at 04:00 (UTC+7) (Indonesia Time)

I've tried custom scheduled query but since the timezone is in UTC, so I can not achieve my requirement.

Sample :

> 1st day of month 04:00
> [image]

How to solve this?
Can we set specific timezone in custom scheduled query in Google BigQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Please update the scheduled query and set the country first. With this you define the time zone as well.

Comment: Hi @Samuel
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule your query based on your [local time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries). For your requirements follow below steps:

`Step 1`: Write your query in the `BigQuery console`.

[image]

`Step 2`: Click the schedule button present at the top and select the option `Create new schedule query`

[image]

`Step 3`:  Below the `heading schedule options` select the `Repeats`option as monthly from the drop down button and select the `start at set time` option radio button.

[image]

`Step 4`: Now click on the calendar icon to select the `country` and `timezone`.

[image]

`Step 5`: select `Indonesia` time zone as per your requirement and set the `date` and `time`.

[image]

`Step 6`: Fill all the required fields and click the `save button`.

Comment: Hi @kiran-mathew , I've tried using your step, and set start time to 1 nov 4 AM WIT(Indo time), but when I check target date for next run is 1 January 2023 4 AM. (It skips 1 December, might be bcs If I set 1 nov, it translates to 31 oct, and since november only have 30 days, then is skipped) –

Comment: @HanChris The observation you made is correct. This is because when you schedule a query based on the local time zone, it gets converted into the UTC. As a workaround you can try to change the Repeat option from Monthly to Custom and specify `1 of month 04:00` or  you can also tweak the run time in a way so that even if it gets converted to UTC it will run on the 1st day of the month.

Comment: Hi @kiran-mathew, thank you for your response. Again, setting custom, can not specify the time zone. If I set 1 of month 04:00, will be converted to 1 of month 11:00 ICT (UTC+7). It's so silly that Google do not provide timezone for the custom value.